# Error building emacs master on Ubuntu: xmenu.c Fx_menu_bar_open_internal undeclared

Tags: build

If this is just a transient problem with the master branch, or more likely a misconfiguration on my part, feel free to let me know.

I'm building emacs from scratch on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm at git commit 703115829b. I'm using GTK3 toolkit. I `apt install`ed the dependencies, configured (outside the source dir), and ran `make` as usual. I get compile errors starting with this one:

```
In file included from ../../emacs/src/xmenu.c:38:0:
../../emacs/src/xmenu.c:355:36: error: ‘Fx_menu_bar_open_internal’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘Sx_menu_bar_open_internal’?
 DEFUN ("x-menu-bar-open-internal", Fx_menu_bar_open_internal, Sx_menu_bar_open_internal, 0, 1, "i",
                                    ^
../../emacs/src/lisp.h:3068:26: note: in definition of macro ‘DEFUN’
        { .a ## maxargs = fnname },     \
                          ^~~~~~
../../emacs/src/xmenu.c:355:36: warning: no previous prototype for ‘Fx_menu_bar_open_internal’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
 DEFUN ("x-menu-bar-open-internal", Fx_menu_bar_open_internal, Sx_menu_bar_open_internal, 0, 1, "i",
                                    ^
../../emacs/src/lisp.h:3070:16: note: in definition of macro ‘DEFUN’
    Lisp_Object fnname
                ^~~~~~
../../emacs/src/xmenu.c: In function ‘menu_position_func’:
../../emacs/src/xmenu.c:1175:21: error: ‘Qframe_monitor_workarea’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘gdk_monitor_get_workarea’?
   workarea = call3 (Qframe_monitor_workarea,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     gdk_monitor_get_workarea
../../emacs/src/xmenu.c:1175:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Makefile:402: recipe for target 'xmenu.o' failed
```

Here's my config results:

```
Configured for 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'.

  Where should the build process find the source code?    ../emacs
  What compiler should emacs be built with?               gcc -g3 -O2
  Should Emacs use the GNU version of malloc?             no
    (The GNU allocators don't work with this system configuration.)
  Should Emacs use a relocating allocator for buffers?    no
  Should Emacs use mmap(2) for buffer allocation?         no
  What window system should Emacs use?                    x11
  What toolkit should Emacs use?                          GTK3
  Where do we find X Windows header files?                Standard dirs
  Where do we find X Windows libraries?                   Standard dirs
  Does Emacs use -lXaw3d?                                 no
  Does Emacs use -lXpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ljpeg?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -ltiff?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use a gif library?                           yes -lgif
  Does Emacs use a png library?                           yes -lpng16 -lz
  Does Emacs use -lrsvg-2?                                no
  Does Emacs use cairo?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -llcms2?                                 no
  Does Emacs use imagemagick?                             no
  Does Emacs use native APIs for images?                  no
  Does Emacs support sound?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgpm?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -ldbus?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -lgconf?                                 no
  Does Emacs use GSettings?                               yes
  Does Emacs use a file notification library?             yes -lglibc (inotify)
  Does Emacs use access control lists?                    no
  Does Emacs use -lselinux?                               no
  Does Emacs use -lgnutls?                                yes
  Does Emacs use -lxml2?                                  no
  Does Emacs use -lfreetype?                              yes
  Does Emacs use HarfBuzz?                                yes
  Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              no
  Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   no
  Does Emacs use -lsystemd?                               no
  Does Emacs use -ljansson?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgmp?                                   yes
  Does Emacs directly use zlib?                           yes
  Does Emacs have dynamic modules support?                yes
  Does Emacs use toolkit scroll bars?                     yes
  Does Emacs support Xwidgets (requires gtk3)?            no
  Does Emacs have threading support in lisp?              yes
  Does Emacs support the portable dumper?                 yes
  Does Emacs support legacy unexec dumping?               no
  Which dumping strategy does Emacs use?                  pdumper
```

Comment: Is that symbol defined in globals.h? Does this go away if you build inside the source tree?

Comment: Aha, yes it does go away if I build inside the source tree! That's good enough for me. And when I build successfully in the source tree, yes it does get defined in globals.h (using EXFUN).